# Graphic Designers: Ubuntu or Studio?

Tags: desktop-environments, ubuntu-studio

For Graphic designers which Ubuntu version is better?

1. Ubuntu (Unity, GNOME)
2. Ubuntu Studio? If yes, how can I install Gnome, Unity or KDE instead of Xfce?

Comment: Why the [tag:16.10] tag? How does your question relate top the upcoming Ubuntu release?

Answer (score 4):

> For Graphic designers which Ubuntu version is better?

It totally does not matter. All official Ubuntu versions are the same; they have the same core and same available applications. The difference is the software that gets installed by default (mainly another desktop environment, some different default apps).

Any high-end system is capable of running any version of Ubuntu and have the software installed used for Ubuntu Studio.

[Here is a list of software used in Studio](http://ubuntustudio.org/tour/). All of these are available through the normal repositories.